# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar líneas de un .txt por otras en python?

Tags: python, robots.txt

Estuve tratando de averiguar cómo puedo borrar y reemplazar una línea específica de un archivo **`.txt`** por la siguiente y la siguiente por la consecutiva y así.

No sé si me explico, pero algo como esto:

> 1.Rocas
> 2.Bellotas
> 3.Madera

Si yo borro la línea 1, la 2 la reemplaza y la tres pasa al lugar de la 2, quedando así:

> 1.Bellotas
> 2.Madera

Para que entiendan un poco más, es un código que armé para simular una función de mochila-inventario de un videojuego. Esta pregunta vendría siendo para construir la opción de "sacar objetos de una mochila". Además para aclarar el script lo implementé en un bot de una red social.

```
#FUNCIÓN PARA CONSULTAR GUARDADO DE PLANTAS

@client.command("guardarplantas1")
def guardarplantas1(data):
    data.subClient.send_message(data.chatId, message="""[bc]¿QUÉ PLANTAS QUIERES GUARDAR?
[CI]Escribe !guardar1 <nombre de la planta>. Esta se almacenará en tu forja y estará protegida.
[c]
[ciu]Para revisar tu forja, escribe !forja1.""", messageType=0)


#FUNCIÓN PARA REVISAR LA FORJA(INVENTARIO)
@client.command()
def forja1(data):
    with open("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Roleplay/bag.txt") as text_file:
        contents = text_file.read()
        data.subClient.send_message(data.chatId, message="""[bcu]Tu forja
[c]""" + contents)
        file.close()
        
#FUNCIÓN PARA GUARDAR PLANTAS
@client.command()
def guardar1(data):
    msg = data.message + "   "
    msg = msg.split(" ")
    msg[3] = msg[2]
    msg[2] = msg[1]
    msg[1] = msg[0]
    msg[0] = 5
    with open('/storage/emulated/0/Download/Roleplay/bag.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write('\n{} {} {}'.format(msg[1], msg[2], msg[3]))
        data.subClient.send_message(data.chatId, message="""[ci]{} {} {} se ha guardado con éxito!""".format(msg[1], msg[2], msg[3]))

#FUNCIÓN PARA SACAR PLANTAS

-(nada)
```

Como ven, aún no se me ocurre cómo puedo hacer esta última función (otra cosa, ignoren esto de `@client.command()` o similares, pues es una dependencia que instalé para hacer este bot en la red social; para que se guíen un poco, esto de `message=` después del `=` va el contenido del mensaje. Esto: `msg = data.message + "   "` sería para obtener el texto del mensaje del usuario que solicita alguna de estas funciones, pero como dije, no le den importancia).

Gracias.

Comment: Los número los tienes en tu txt o solo lo usas para simbolizar la línea?

Comment: Los uso para simbolizar la línea

Comment: La forma difícil es moverse por el archivo con `seek()` y la forma fácil es leer el archivo, convertirlo a lista y eliminar su elemento y luego volver a escribir el archivo

Comment: @Christian. Hay que evitar cargas masivas de datos. Siempre que sea posible, procesar por lotes para minimizar uso de RAM y CPU (por la creación/eliminación masiva de objetos, garbage collection).

Answer (score 1):

Esta función elimina una línea de un archivo:

```
def elimina_lineas(entrada, salida, linea_eliminar):
    """
    Elimina un conjunto de lineas de un archivo.
    :param entrada: El nombre del archivo de entrada.
    :param salida: El nombre del archivo de salida.
    :param lineas: Número de linea a eliminar
    """
    with open(entrada, "rt") as arch_in:
        with open(salida, "wt") as arch_out:
            nro_linea = 1
            for linea_in in arch_in:
                if nro_linea != linea_eliminar:
                    arch_out.write(linea_in)
                nro_linea += 1
```

La función abre el archivo de entrada y graba cada línea en el archivo de salida, excepto la línea indicada por el parámetro `linea_eliminar` (cuenta a partir de 1).

**Demo**

*entrada.txt*

```
linea 1
linea 2
linea 3
linea 4
linea 5
linea 6
linea 7
linea 8
```

*código*

```
elimina_lineas("entrada.txt", "salida.txt", 3)
```

*salida.txt*

```
linea 1
linea 2
linea 4
linea 5
linea 6
linea 7
linea 8
```